# JAVA - selenium 4 - Firefox : How to avoid detection + login to gmail ERROR

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gmail, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to automate the connexion to gmail with selenium 4.
but I get the following message:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lvoS.png)

how can i disable the detection ?
I have tried all the solutions that exist in the web now, but no result :(

Please Help !

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some common client-side checks done by many websites to block selenium and other automated browsers.

```
window._phantom
window.webdriver
window.domAutomation
window.$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_
document.$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_
window.document.documentElement.getAttribute('webdriver')
navigator.webdriver
window.document.documentElement.getAttribute('driver')
window.document.documentElement.getAttribute('selenium')
window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Array
window.__nightmare
window._Selenium_IDE_Recorder
window.__$webdriverAsyncExecutor
window.__driver_evaluate
window.__selenium_evaluate
window.domAutomationController
window.calledSelenium
window.callSelenium
```

Majority of checks are in the window, navigator and document javascript object. You can spoof these values using javascript. Make sure your javascript is executed prior to that of the website's.

Using Selenium for emails is overkill. I'd highly suggest looking into the Jakarta Mail API for a much easier, less consumptive approach.